# Can't add accents in certain apps

Tags: keyboard, input-devices, input-method

In certain programs, I can't add accents.

In most programs and packages, I just press `´`, and then `a`, turning it to an `á`.

In other packages it doesn't work:

- In Telegram Desktop it turns into an `a` instead.
- In WPS Office, and WINE, it turns into `´a`.

Disabling `qdbus` has no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running ibus-daemon? Or maybe setting QT_IM_MODULE=xim... I don't know which one is better.
There is a discussion in Telegram's github:
https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/1041